# I can't access resources in peered VNet

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I have 2 VNets (both in the same region - North Europe). In one of the VNets I have API Management service, which has a private IP. In second VNet I created a VM. I'd like to be able to access API Management service residing in the first VNet from the VM that exists in second VNet.

I created a peering between those VNets (from VNet1 to VNet 2 and from VNet 2 to Vnet 1). I used default settings.

I'd expect to be able to see the other VNet from my VM and to be able to access the API Management Service.

Here's the result of `ifconfig` from VM:

```sh
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.21.0.4  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.21.0.255
        inet6 fe80::20d:3aff:fed8:9895  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0d:3a:d8:98:95  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 24274  bytes 25832495 (25.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 12101  bytes 2419540 (2.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1614  bytes 185968 (185.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1614  bytes 185968 (185.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`eth0` is the VNet that my VM belongs to. However, I thought I'd also see here the connection with the other VNet.
Pinging my API Management Instance Service (with its private IP) also fails.

Did I miss some step?

Comment: you wouldn't see a connection, because its just another route. can you show your peering config. do you have UDR's or NSG's or both?

Answer (score 1):

You would not see a connection for the API Management service with `ifconfig`. If you want to ensure VNet peering is working, you can add an Azure VM as the same Vnet as the API Management service VNet then ping Azure VMs each other. You can not ping API management service with its private IP as the document states:

> **API Management service does not listen to requests coming from IP
>   addresses**. It only responds to requests to the host name configured on
>   its service endpoints. These endpoints include gateway, the Azure
>   portal and the Developer portal, direct management endpoint, and Git.

For more reference:

[How to use Azure API Management with virtual networks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet)

[Using Azure API Management service with an internal virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-internal-vnet)